# OpenCL - results are not the same as CPU version

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencl

I want to use openCl for a pixel value comparison between two images. One image should be "transformed" by a transformation matrix.

**1)** I am facing one problem, that the result of the openCL version is not the same as the CPU version.
The pixel value difference is in my example images (imageA: all pixels are 5, imagesB: all pixel are 6) always one, so in total with 1000*1000 pixels it should be 1000000.
The CPU version is always correct, but the openCL version is always a little unprecise and also differs from time to time (e.g. 998895 or 998829).

**2)** Another issue I have is the runtime, because adding the difference of two compared pixel to a result variable, takes a long time. But my feelings says that it could be solved through another memory layout.

Any ideas for the problems I have?
Maybe also the way of using a two dimensional workingset leads to mistakes?

Thank you and kind regards
Hendrik

Here is the kernel:
Basically it gets two images and 700 transformation matrices (at the moment all are representing the identity).

```
__kernel void compliance(
        __read_only image2d_t imageA,
        __read_only image2d_t imageB,
        __constant float *matrix,
        __global int *result
    ) 
{


    for (int i = 0; i < 700; i++)
    {
        size_t x = get_global_id(0);
        size_t y = get_global_id(1);

        float t1 = matrix[0 + i * 6];
        float t2 = matrix[1 + i * 6];
        float t3 = matrix[2 + i * 6];
        float t4 = matrix[3 + i * 6];
        float t5 = matrix[4 + i * 6];
        float t6 = matrix[5 + i * 6];

        //calculate the other coords of the comparing pixel
        int x_new = x * t1 + y * t2 + 1 * t3;
        int y_new = x * t4 + y * t5 + 1 * t6;

        int a = (read_imagei(imageA, (int2)(x, y)).x);
        int b = (read_imagei(imageB, (int2)(x_new, y_new)).x);
        int diff = b - a;

        //add every different of two compared pixels to the result
        result[i] += diff;
    }
}
```

Here is my host code:

```
#define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#include <CL/cl.hpp>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <opencv2\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui.hpp>


using namespace std;




int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //700 transformation matrices
    int numberMatrices = 700;
    bool opencl = true;
    //iamge width
    int width = 1000;
    //image height
    int height = 1000;
    //total number of pixels of one image
    int size = width*height;


    // Create two example images
    const int LIST_SIZE = size;
    int *imageA = new int[LIST_SIZE];
    int *imageB = new int[LIST_SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
        //every pixel value of imageA is 5
        imageA[i] = 5;
        //every pixel value of imageA is 6
        imageB[i] = 6;
    }

    //creation of n transformation matrices
    const int MATRIX_SIZE = 6* numberMatrices;
    float *indi = new float[MATRIX_SIZE];
    //all the matrices are the same
    for (int i = 0; i < numberMatrices; i++)
    {
        //identity matrix
        indi[0 + i * 6] = 1;
        indi[1 + i * 6] = 0;
        indi[2 + i * 6] = 0;
        indi[3 + i * 6] = 0;
        indi[4 + i * 6] = 1;
        indi[5 + i * 6] = 0;
    }

    //array to save the results of the comparison
    const int RESULT_SIZE = numberMatrices;
    int *result = new int[RESULT_SIZE];





    if (opencl)
    {
        try {
            // Get available platforms
            vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
            cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
            std::cerr << "Platform number is: " << platforms.size() << std::endl;
            std::string platformVendor;
            platforms[0].getInfo((cl_platform_info)CL_PLATFORM_VENDOR, &platformVendor);
            std::cerr << "Platform is by: " << platformVendor << "\n";

            // Select the default platform and create a context using this platform and the GPU
            cl_context_properties cps[3] = {
                CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM,
                (cl_context_properties)(platforms[0])(),
                0
            };
            cl::Context context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, cps);

            vector<cl::ImageFormat> format;
            context.getSupportedImageFormats(CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, CL_MEM_OBJECT_IMAGE2D, &format);
            /*  for (int i = 0; i < format.size(); i++)
            {
            cout << "Channel Data Type: " << format.at(i).image_channel_data_type
            << "    Channel order: "  << format.at(i).image_channel_order << endl;
            }*/



            // Get a list of devices on this platform
            vector<cl::Device> devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
            for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++)
            {

                cout << "Device: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>() << endl;
                cout << "DOUBLE FP: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_DOUBLE_FP_CONFIG>() << endl;
                cout << "Image Max Height: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_IMAGE2D_MAX_HEIGHT>() << endl;
                cout << "Image Support: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_IMAGE_SUPPORT>() << endl;
                cout << "Local Memory Size: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE>() << endl;
                cout << "Clock Frequency: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_CLOCK_FREQUENCY>() << endl;
                cout << "CUs: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS>() << endl;
                cout << "Driver: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DRIVER_VERSION>() << endl;
                cout << "Version: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_VERSION>() << endl;
                cout << "Work Group: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE>() << endl;
                cout << "Items: " << devices.at(i).getInfo<CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_ITEM_DIMENSIONS>();
                cout << endl;
            }


            //Create opencl image
            cl::Image2D clImage_A = cl::Image2D(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, cl::ImageFormat(CL_RGBA, CL_UNSIGNED_INT8), (size_t)width, (size_t)height, 0, imageA);
            cl::Image2D clImage_B = cl::Image2D(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, cl::ImageFormat(CL_RGBA, CL_UNSIGNED_INT8), (size_t)width, (size_t)height, 0, imageB);


            // Create a command queue and use the first device
            cl::CommandQueue queue = cl::CommandQueue(context, devices[0]);

            // Read kernel source file
            std::ifstream sourceFile("difference.cl");
            std::string sourceCode(
                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(sourceFile),
                (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
            cl::Program::Sources source(1, std::make_pair(sourceCode.c_str(), sourceCode.length() + 1));

            // Make program of the source code in the context
            cl::Program program = cl::Program(context, source);

            // Build program for these specific devices
            program.build(devices);

            // Make kernel
            cl::Kernel kernel(program, "compliance");


            // Create memory buffers
            cl::Buffer buffer_matrix = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, LIST_SIZE * sizeof(float));
            cl::Buffer buffer_result = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, RESULT_SIZE * sizeof(int));

            // Copy list of results to the memory buffers
            queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(buffer_matrix, CL_TRUE, 0, MATRIX_SIZE * sizeof(float), indi);


            // Set arguments to kernel
            kernel.setArg(0, clImage_A);
            kernel.setArg(1, clImage_B);
            kernel.setArg(2, buffer_matrix);
            kernel.setArg(3, buffer_result);


            cl::Event event;

            std::cout << "Start OpenCL processing.." << endl;
            chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            // Run the kernel n-times on specific ND range
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(
                    kernel,
                    cl::NullRange,
                    cl::NDRange((size_t)width, (size_t)height),
                    cl::NDRange(1, 1),
                    NULL,
                    &event);
                cout << i << " ";
                event.wait();
            }

            chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

            auto duration_opencl = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();


            std::cout << "OpenCL processing done.." << endl;
            std::cout << "Start CPU Processing.." << endl;


            // Read buffer_result into result
            queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer_result, CL_TRUE, 0, RESULT_SIZE * sizeof(int), result);


            //cpu version to calculate the difference between the two arryays
            t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            int different = 0;
            int x_new;
            int x;
            for (int i = 0; i < numberMatrices; i++)
            {
                different = 0;
                for (int n = 0; n < LIST_SIZE; n++)
                {
                    x = imageA[n];
                    x_new = x;;
                    int a = imageA[x];
                    int b = imageB[x_new];
                    int diff = imageB[x_new] - imageA[x];

                    different += diff;
                }

            }

            t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
            auto duration_cpu = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
            std::cout << "CPU processing done.." << endl;


            //output of the results
            std::cout << "opencl: diff " << result[0] << endl;
            std::cout << "Runtime opencl: " << duration_opencl << endl;

            std::cout << "CPU: diff " << different << endl;
            std::cout << "Runtime CPU: " << duration_cpu << endl;

            double times = (double)duration_cpu / (double)duration_opencl;
            std::cout << "OpenCL is  " << times << " times faster!!!"  << endl;

            char c;
            std::cin >> c;

        }
        catch (cl::Error error) {
            std::cout << error.what() << "(" << error.err() << ")" << std::endl;
            char c;
            std::cin >> c;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: one term I have found is reduction. Here a link to a ppt. I have not worked on it, but maybe someone has the same problem: http://www.fz-juelich.de/SharedDocs/Downloads/IAS/JSC/EN/slides/advanced-gpu/adv-gpu-opencl-reduction.pdf?__blob=publicationFile

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think that you have race condition here case in this line `result[i] += diff;` of your OpenCL code your program do it in each work item simultaneously? So maybe it could be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, that could be a problem. That is also the source for the slow runtime. Do you know another way to save the sum of diferrences of each pixel pair?

Comment: you can use different methods as I know OpenCL has [atomic functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atomicFunctions.html): `atomic_add(result[i], diff)` and you can [use barriers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/barrier.html) to prevent simultaneousl writing in the same memory place

Comment: thanks...although I have not succesfully implemented the atomic_add yet. the problem is mentioned as **parallel reduction**

Answer (score 0):

The floating point arithmetics differ on the platforms. You are very likely seeing the effect of a hardware specific [MAD](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/mad.html) optimization performed by the `OpenCL` compiler. As far as I know, disabling optimizations using `-cl-opt-disable` will not help in this case.